# How do I set up and run a leisure cycling crew?

Tags: advocacy

Any advice on setting up and running a cycling crew?
I have absolutely no experience in this and am curious to see what the community had to say from experience.

It is almost always more fun to have someone to share the stoke

Comment: Ryan, welcome to the site. Questions here should be specific and answerable; this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please read [our FAQ](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details. I'm voting to close this, but consider editing this to ask about specific issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a group that gets together for leisure cycling once a week or so?  There's no "formula" for this -- you start with two or three others who are interested in doing rides and, if it "works", more will find out and join you, or you may post a notice at local bike shops, on grocery store bulletin boards, etc.

You may want to decide in advance what sort of riding you want to do -- obviously on-road vs off-road, but also how far, how fast, what sort of routes, etc.  Also think about when -- during the day weekdays, in the evening, weekends, etc.  Though be prepared to be flexible if the group's desires are a bit different from yours.